# True antonym to braggart/exhibitionist?

Tags: american-english, antonyms

Braggart is a noun meaning someone who boasts about their achievements. Exhibitionist is also a noun meaning a person who acts in an extravagant way. Another example of a word in this synonym-family is "show-off".

I am having a lot of trouble thinking of a true antonym for these. Sure, humble or humility work well, but one is an adjective and the other is a noun that someone possesses.

What is a word for a PERSON who is humble or someone who has humility. A word that means "humble person" in the same way "braggart" means "boastful person".

Thank you.

Comment: A "reserved", "modest", "discrete" or "shy" person.

Comment: @Graffito "Discreet" is likely what you meant. "Discrete" means something else.

Comment: Please define 'true' antonym, especially given the context of your request for a true antonym (singular) for different words.

Comment: @Deepak - yes, I meant "discreet" (*marked by prudence or modesty and wise self-restraint*), and not "discrete" (*distinct*) . Shameful mistake :(.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a noun you're demanding, the closest I can find is **[introvert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/introvert)**:

> **introvert** *n* **1.** a shy person

Comment: Your answer would be strengthened by providing an explanation of *why* introvert is suitable, with such supporting dictionary definitions, examples, or other references that may be appropriate. I would disagree; being an extravert is orthagonal to being a blowhard or a ham or a showoff.

Comment: @choster hows this?

Answer (score 0):

"Humble" and it's variants would tend to be the natural antonyms here. Most of the other options I think of would be indirect antonyms. That said, consider:

- Reserved
- Modest or Discreet (Mentioned in a previous comment)
- Quietly Confident
- Modest

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you add some (linked) definitions to prove your answer?